# User InputBox For Loop Error

Tags: vba, excel, quandl

I keep getting

> Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range

I'm trying to allow the user to determine what stocks they would like to download from [QUANDL](https://www.quandl.com/)

```
Dim stock1 As Variant  
Dim stock2 As Variant  
Dim i As Integer  
Dim stock() As Variant  
ReDim stock(i) As Variant  
stock1 = InputBox("Stock? Enter all in uppercase")  
stock2 = InputBox("Stock?")  
Range("B2").Value = "YAHOO/" & stock1 & "/6"
Range("C2").Value = "YAHOO/" & stock2 & "/6"

For i = 3 To 30  
    If stock(i) = InputBox("Stock?") Then
    Range(Cells(2, 1 + i)) = "YAHOO/" & stock(i) & "/6"
    ElseIf stock(i) = "last" Then
    Exit For
    End If
Next i
```

The `If stock(i) = inputbox("Stock?") Then` line keeps getting the error.

Comment: when you redim stock(i) i is not assigned so it is 0 which is fine, but then in the for loop you try to get stock(3) whcih does not exist.  Change the redim to `redim stock(3 to 30)`

Answer (score 1):

You haven't assigned any value to `i` before you use it in the `ReDim` statement.  An unassigned integer has an `Empty` or `0` value:

Redimensioning the array to `i`, which per above has an empty/0 value:

```
ReDim stock(i) As Variant
```

is equivalent to:

```
ReDim stock(0) As Variant
```

So, in your loop, any value of `i` which is greater than 0 will raise that error.